# Resizing a notebook with a command

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interface

I've got some notebooks which my friend wrote on a different computer, presumably with a much higher resolution screen to mine. When I try to open them on my computer, the window size of the notebook is larger than my screen resolution, and the menu bar at the top of the notebook is placed up above the top of my screen. This means I can't click and drag to move the window around, and I also can't resize it using the buttons at the top right of the window. I think it would be fair to say that this is a bug in Mathematica, it seems like pretty undesirable behaviour to me. I just need a practical solution for it really though so I can get on with my work.

I've run a few different commands to try to resize the notebook's window but none of them worked. Can someone tell me a command I can evaluate inside the notebook which will resize it to fill my screen so that it's no longer going off the edges?
I'm also open to a different method to fix this problem, maybe in the GUI or in the terminal, but a Mathematica command seems like it would be more widely applicable. I'm running Ubuntu with LXQT as my GUI.

Comment: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> {400, 300}]` ?

Comment: As I recall I tried this before and it resized the window but left the menu bar off the top of the screen still. I've had another look and it seems that `WindowMargins` is the option I need. I must have overlooked it before, the name is not very intuitive to me.

Comment: This should do what you want : `FrontEndTokenExecute@"StackWindows"`